# Riak CS disable authorization

Tags: riak, riak-cs

Is there a way to completely disable authorization in `RiakCS(S2)` and `Stanchion`? By completely I mean ***completely***. I don't need it anyway and step with manual user creation is hard to fit in automated deployment process, which I really need. Or maybe there is another way to create required `admin` user with **my own** key id and secret?

---

Please, do not suggest me to change my deployment process. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an external API to do that, but internal function call [1] may help.

[1] Be able to set key and secret for a user for riak-cs https://github.com/basho/riak_cs/issues/1074#issuecomment-111110461

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that I can invoke Erlang shell.